# Dependency Injecting without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know that there are two ways of Dependency injective with Annotation and xml. I've tried the annotation way and everything works fine but when I trying the xml way, something doesn't seem to make sense for me. From my controller I need to call the LabSoftDAOImpl object and call the method. In the LabSoftDAOImpl class I also need to set the datasource because it will be doing queries. Now I'm confused on how to call a new instance of the LabSoftDAOImpl and then set its datasource using the setter injection.

Here is my spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.peep.ehr.dependencyBuilder , com.peep.ehr.versionTool , com.peep.ehr.surescript" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
    <bean id="dataSourceSureScripts"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="xxxxxx" />
    <property name="url"
        value="xxxxx" />
    <property name="username" value="xxxxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>

<bean id="providerDao" class="com.peep.ehr.surescript.ProviderDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSureScripts" />
</bean>

<bean id="artifactDao" class="com.peep.ehr.versionTool.ArtifactDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="labSoftDao" class="com.peep.ehr.labSoft.LabSoftDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSourceSureScripts" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:labsoft.properties">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="labsoft" class="com.peep.ehr.labSoft.LabSoft">
    <property name="ehrKey" value="${labsoft.Key}" />
    <property name="ehrPrefix" value="${labsoft.Prefix}" />
</bean>

<bean id="labsoftController" class="com.peep.ehr.labSoft.LabSoftController">
    <property name="LabSoft" ref="labsoft" />
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class LabSoftController {
static LabSoft  lb;

String practiceName;

LabSoft LabSoft;

LabSoftDAOImpl labSoftMethods;


public void setLabSoftDAOImpl(LabSoftDAOImpl labsoftimpl){
    labSoftMethods = labsoftimpl;
}


public void setLabSoft(LabSoft labsoft){
    LabSoft = labsoft;
}
    ....
```

LabSoftDAOImpl

```
public class LabSoftDAOImpl implements LabSoftDAO, InitializingBean {

private DataSource dataSource;
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    if (dataSource == null) {
        throw new BeanCreationException("Must set dataSource on LabSoftDAOImpl");
    }
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<bean id="labsoftController" class="com.peep.ehr.labSoft.LabSoftController">
    <property name="LabSoft" ref="labsoft" />
    <property name="labSoftDao" ref="labSoftDao" />
</bean>
```

In the **LabSoftController**

```
private LabSoftDAO labSoftDao;

public void setLabSoftDao(LabSoftDAO labSoftDao){
    this.labSoftDao = labSoftDao;
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar but only was calling LabSoftDAOImpl. Why does it work with the interface class but not its implementation? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jaspreet Chauhan You did not set labSoftDao for your controller in your xml at all. Using interfaces is good practice.